# Is there a sub-folder only monitoring (in a given git repo) in on-premises TFS 2015 Update 3?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We would like to host multiple projects in a given git repo and have sub-folder level monitoring for CI. For example:

In a git repo called "Foo", we would like to have following projects:

1. Foo.Library1 (Would like to publish nuget library called Foo.Library1 with CI)
2. Foo.Library2 (Would like to publish nuget library called Foo.Library2 with CI)

But when I make a check in code for Library2, I do not want CI for Foo.Library1 to kick in and vice versa.

I was told that this is not possible in TFS 2015, Update 3 (On-premises version).

Can someone confirm or disprove this? If disproving, can you please provide steps on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no way to **limit the CI trigger** to a specific folder within the repo on *TFS 2015 Update3*. There is a feature request on the Microsoft UserVoice site and got completed:

> [Allow GIT CI Builds to monitor changes only in a specific
>   subdirectory of a Repo](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5279254-allow-git-ci-builds-to-monitor-changes-only-in-a-s)
>
> This feature will ship in **TFS 15** and is already available on VSTS
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2016#june-14.
>
> *Team Services Group (Product group, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  ·  August 23, 2016*

Then you can do it  with **path filters** on TFS15 and VSTS. Details please refer: [GIT filter](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#git-filters)